# Gradient Boost regressor clarification of the algorithm

Tags: regression, boosting

I was watching this [video](https://youtu.be/2xudPOBz-vs?t=1268) (time stamp: 21:08) that explains how the algorithm works, and although it was clear for the most part there is one thing I didn't understand.

How can a single sample end up in multiple leaves? Isn't the point of decision trees to separate the samples by some threshold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video author addresses this in the Corrections section of his Description:

> 21:08. With regression trees, the sample will only go to a single leaf, and this summation simply isolates the one output value of interest from all of the others. However, when I first made this video I was thinking that because Gradient Boost is supposed to work with any "weak learner", not just small regression trees, that this summation was a way to add flexibility to the algorithm.

And indeed the stochastic gradient descent paper he references earlier doesn't include a summation.

All that said, the Quinlan family of tree algorithms splits instances across different paths as a treatment for missing values, so if you wanted to boost Quinlan trees that summation would be important.